# Should Luke's lightsaber have given away his plan?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

During Luke's confrontation of Kylo Ren toward the end of *The Last Jedi* we see that

> the lightsaber Luke uses a **blue** lightsaber (which I thought was his original one but that really doesn't matter), not the **green** one of his own construction.

Given that Kylo Ren  and Rey has just

> fought over and broken the blue lightsaber

Why did Kylo Ren *not* notice this "inconsistency" and realize that

> Luke's physical body was not there?

Comment: Are you sure it was that one? I didn't see too closely, but it looked like it was a different model which just happened to be blue.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy, would the Luke have left it at Maz's before he went into exile? Or did he lose it before?

Comment: @JeremyFrench See edits. Also, not trying to spoil anything in the comments, but the *color* is what was important, not the model.

Comment: @JeremyFrench it was indeed the lightsaber the post referenced - I paid really close attention to that when it lit up the wrong color

Comment: Whew - I was afraid you were going to tell me Luke has a talking lightsaber now....

Comment: If only Luke knew how to construct a lightsaber. He could just make one that looks like his first blade.

Comment: Did Kylo Ren even know that Luke was capable of Force Projection? Did any Jedi or Sith ever do that trick before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has now been directly addressed in [an interview with director Rian Johnson](http://www.ign.com/articles/2018/01/10/why-did-luke-skywalker-use-a-blue-lightsaber-against-kylo-ren-in-star-wars-the-last-jedi).

First, he explains that Luke is tailoring his projection specifically enrage Kylo.

> "**[Luke] is basically tailoring this projection to have maximum effect on Kylo,"** Johnson explained. **"He knows that Kylo’s Achilles heel is his rage, and so that’s why he kind of makes himself look younger, the way Kylo would’ve last seen him in their confrontation at the temple,  and that’s why he decided to bring Kylo’s grandfather’s lightsaber down there** -- the lightsaber that Kylo screamed at Rey, ‘that’s mine, that belongs to me.’" As far as Johnson's concerned, **Luke believes that Anakin's lightsaber will have a much more visceral impact on the erstwhile Ben Solo than Luke's own green blade.**

So why doesn't Kylo Ren notice it? According to Johnson, Kylo Ren doesn't totally know what happened to the lightsaber.

> "We as an audience saw that... The truth is, we see the lightsaber split in half -- **Kylo sees a blinding flash of light and is knocked unconscious, and then Rey takes the lightsaber away before he wakes up,**" he said. "So if you really want to dig into it and get an explanation, **you can say that he doesn’t 100 percent know what happened to the lightsaber.**"

Answer (score 91):

Luke has no way of knowing that his blue lightsaber had been destroyed. He was on Ahch-To when it happened and presumably was still cut off from the Force.

As for why Kylo didn't notice the inconsistency, that's an intentional choice by the filmmakers. You may have noticed during the fight that at one point they zoom in on Luke's feet. It was previously established that the planet has a thin layer of salt, and stepping on it leave bright red footprints. **Kylo also fails to realize that Luke isn't leaving footprints**. His emotions and hatred blind him to the obvious.

Comment: Well I totally missed the no footprints as well!! You make a good point, but it still doesn't make sense why Luke would choose a lightsaber he didn't have in his possession. He has been using his green one since RotJ... Kylo would know Luke as using the green one.

Comment: @Skooba not necessarily. I got the impression that Kylo knew Rey was with Luke when they were connecting.

Comment: @phantom42 Yes, but Rey and Kylo had just [see second spoiler in question]. Shouldn't that rule the blue one out?

Comment: Things Luke knows: Kylo knows about the existence of the Anakin saber; Kylo and Rey were connecting. Things Luke doesn't know: Anakin saber is destroyed. It's a bit sloppy, but I think acceptable that Luke believes he should be using the Anakin saber. Also, it's sort of a mind-game, isn't it? He's there to throw Kylo off - what better saber to "use" than one that Kylo is obsessed with in an effort to enrage him even further?

Comment: I think it's also possible that Luke would have considered this and figured it'd seem more like Luke was teamed up with Rey if Luke used the Lightsaber Kylo assumes Rey has, not knowing it was already destroyed.

Comment: Also, what's to say that Luke doesn't have *another* blue lightsaber?  I don't think it's unreasonable for him to have constructed more than one, it's been a few years since the last time he and Kylo saw each other.  Kylo could easily have assumed the green one was lost/destroyed in the fire at the Jedi academy.

Comment: re footprints, oooooooooooooooooooh. OHHH. See, it's easy to miss these things. Simple answer: Kylo was fooled. End of

Comment: With the footprints, I noticed, but I thought their emphasis on Kylo's feet were to convey that he was telegraphing his strikes by moving before attacking, and that Luke was pulling a "Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon" sort of thing to avoid doing the same.

Comment: Luke had re-opened himself to the force before Rey left Ahch-To. Remember him seeing Ren with Rey and then force-blasting apart the hut? Not that that necessarily means he knew about the lightsaber being destroyed but worth mentioning nonetheless.

Answer (score 71):

Could it be something else:

> Luke is choosing to present an idealized version of himself, he looks younger, he beard is dyed and trimmed. He is choosing the ideal lightsaber for him the Legendary one. This is not Luke as he is, this is the *legendary* Luke Skywalker, coming to save the day. Him arriving is a huge morale boost for the Resistance as much as anything. It harks back to some things he talks to Rey about earlier in the film.

The details of his appearance are inconsequential to Kilo Ren, as @TenthJustice says he is blinded to what is in front of his eyes. In fact

> Looking nearly as Kylo Ren remembers him, possibly plays to his rage better than a wizened old man would.

Comment: I like Legendary aspect of your reasoning.

Comment: I think this is probably the more 'correct' answer, given the talk about becoming a legend earlier in the film. I hadn't thought of this while viewing the movie, but it makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Good point about his appearance being the Legendary Luke Skywalker. I decided his appearance was the way it was when he had last been seen by anyone (Kylo and Leia). Only Rey and Chewie know his beard is gray and his hair is shaggy.

Comment: Are these quotes from somewhere? If so, please provide attribution. If they are not quotes, and just your own thoughts, please remove the quotation embedding.

Comment: @TylerH it's spoiler tags, not quotes.

Comment: @JeremyFrench Ah, for some reason when I scrolled down the first time, the spoiler text was already visible.

Answer (score 16):

Remember that Kylo has no way of knowing how many light sabers there are. Luke has been gone for years. Maybe he built another one. Blue is a fairly common lightsaber color in canon. Obi-Wan's was also blue.

Kylo was also not exactly being *rational*, a point the movie went *way* out of its way to emphasize. I mean he does

> have half a dozen AT-ATs shoot at Luke continuously for a ridiculously long time, until Hux finally makes them stop

I don't have a problem with him missing a minor detail, like the color of a lightsaber.

Comment: This is very true. For all Kylo knows, Luke, in addition to or alternatively to building another lightsaber, could have recovered other older lightsabers. Perhaps Vader kept Obi-Wan's blue lightsaber and Luke later recovered it.

Comment: Is constructing a lightsaber even supposed to be that difficult, even? Kylo Ren apparently made his own despite clearly being less experienced. Luke managed to put together his second lightsaber himself, without outside help. In TLG's flashbacks, Kylo Ren had a blue lightsaber, which seems to hint that all the trainees had their own. Sure seems to indicate that Luke absolutely could have acquired multiple other lightsabers (and in fact probably should have had spares around from the trainees). I don't see any reason Kylo Ren would question the saber colour as a result.